# RedirectToAction MVC 3 after $.ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, redirect

From my view I am sending via $.ajax a JSON object to my controller to save it in the database. 
If all succeeded i want to redirect to another action which will show a diferent view.

If i use this code:

```
return RedirectToAction("CreatePage", "Survey", new {id = question.PageId});
```

The execution goes to the Survey controller which returns a view but it is not shown.

I have read some post which said that it is not posible to redirect via ajax.

The solution I use so far is to redirect via javascript like this:

```
success: function (ret) {
            window.location.href = "/Survey/CreatePage/" + $("#PageId").val();
         }
```

Although this always works, sometimes i need to refresh the CreatePage view to show the last changes made.

Any idea of how to solve this problem better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My first thought is why is this being done with ajax? Is there ever a case where it wouldn't redirect after the post? You mention it would redirect if all succeeded, but you could handle redirecting to an error page, or the same page with an error message. Ajax isn't called for in all cases - it's a tool and should be used only when appropriate.

Comment: Are you expecting HTML or JSON back from your AJAX request? The reason I ask is if you accept JSON back you could in theory make a wrapper response for every AJAX JSON request that has some common properties such as: .Success, .Message, .Data and .Redirect. Your JS can evaluate what properies were sent back on the AJAX to determine if it needs to update a message or maybe do a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mccow002 suggested, I wasn't really needing to make the call via AJAX for that part. After studying the solutions suggested, i realized that i could simple submit it in a form. My confusion came because I have a save and continue editing and a save. For the save and continue I use the AJAX call, but for the save option with the form being submitted is ok.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting to a new page, you can send a rendered html from .net code back to client and load that html in page, like this `$("#main").load(renderedHtml)`.

But for refreshing the page you can write a simple script that run at specified intervals and refresh the page contens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[OutputCache]` on the CreatePage action so that it doesn't cache the page or only caches for so long.

[output caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)